# Switch to Previous IFRAME Selenium Python

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch to the previous frame.

In my code

1. I switch to a frame **(BRCT1Frame)**,
2. Click a button that opens a new window
3. Switch to a new window
4. Switch to the frame inside of the window
5. Insert data & save which closes both the window and frame

However, there is a frame that is before the **BRVT1Frame** that I need to switch to.

Here is My Code:

```
BRT1Frame=driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    buttons=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button")
    for button in buttons:
        if button.text.strip()=="Create Community":
            button.click()

    #A new pop up window causes me to switch windows
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    BRT=driver.switch_to_window(handle)
    print(BRT)

#then I switch frames
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("FormDialogIFrame"))   
driver.find_element_by_id("CommunityFormCommunityNameTextBox").send_keys("1st MEB STAFFEX")

save=driver.find_element_by_id("CommunityFormSaveButton").click()
#that popup closes now I have to switch to another frame
```

The frame I am trying to switch to code:

```
<iframe role="presentation" 
class="x-component x-window-item x-component-default"
src="/brvt?lang=en_US&amp;owf=true&amp;themeName=a_default&amp;
themeContrast=standard&amp;themeFontSize=12" 
name="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;778a1259-bc80-602e-c0ad-16a3f9220516&quot;,&quot;containerVersion&quot;:&quot;7-GA&quot;,&quot;webContextPath&quot;:&quot;/owf&quot;,&quot;preferenceLocation&quot;:&quot;https://www.url,com;,&quot;relayUrl&quot;:&quot;https://url.com/55js/even/rpc_relay.uncompressed.html&quot;,&quot;lang&quot;:&quot;en_US&quot;,&quot;currentTheme&quot;:{&quot;themeName&quot;:&quot;a_default&quot;,&quot;themeContrast&quot;:&quot;standard&quot;,&quot;themeFontSize&quot;:12},&quot;55f&quot;:true,&quot;layout&quot;:&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;/brvt&quot;,&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;260f0022-66de-a78b-3ce8-8de63a3bdbec&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:1,&quot;locked&quot;:false}" 
id="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;778a1259-bc80-602e-c0ad-16a3f9220516&quot;}" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have tried to do this:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

this worked but when I tried to click a drop down menu inside of the frame:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#OYk3vd6NKj1jbrnew > td.sub_item_text").click()
```

I have also tried:

```
 driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;778a1259-bc80-602e-c0ad-16a3f9220516&quot;}")
```

I get an error that states that it is unable to locate the element. 
Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want  to locate exact frame that you specified, then try:

```
required_frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@role="presentation"]')
driver.switch_to_frame(required_frame)
```

or even more specific:

```
required_frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@role="presentation"][@class="x-component x-window-item x-component-default"]')
driver.switch_to_frame(required_frame)
```

Does this advise was helpful?